# Explained - Problems deploying a production NextJS application via Microsoft Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, next.js

Having issues deploying your NextJS app to Microsoft Azure WebApp Service via the Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Issues can vary from `Error: Cannot find module '../build/output/log' on next start` to complete pipeline failures.

Do I need a `server.js`? What should my `package.json` scripts look like? How does a proper pipeline setup look like for this use case?

The solution is rather simple, you can find it listed below:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to deploy a NextJS production build successfully on an Azure WebApp using Azure DevOps' Pipelines, this is how I got it sorted out:

Pipeline `deployment.yml`:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  azureSubscription: 'confidential'
  webAppName: $(HORIZON)
  environmentName: $(HORIZON)
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build Horizon
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install node.js'

    - script: yarn
      displayName: 'Install dependencies'
    
    - script: yarn export
      displayName: 'Export production build'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy Horizon
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool: 
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: $(HORIZON)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'yarn start'
```

The scripts in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start -p $PORT",
    "export": "next build && next export"
  },
```

And my `server.js` (very important):

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/p/:id', (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = '/post'
    const queryParams = { title: req.params.id }
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
  })

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:' + port)
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Extra `.gitignore`:

```
// .gitnignore

build/
.next/
out/
.env
.env.build
node_modules/
jspm_packages/
/.pnp
.pnp.js
dist/
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock
lib-cov
coverage
.nyc_output
bower_components
.npm
*.tgz
.yarn-integrity
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Comment: Greate ! You could accept your answer. Then other users could know that the answer can work. Thanks

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I meant to do that but SO required me to wait for a couple of days (forgot to get back to it) - thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Interestingly, the detail I needed was how the `start` script was written. Setting it to `next start` as the docs say was giving me the same error However, pointing it directly to the `node_modules/next/dist/bin/next` did the trick for me. A little annoying and odd, but I'll take it.

Comment: @pseudoramble Had the same problem originally, posted this solution as I assumed others would be facing it as well - it's not neat but does the trick. I know someone identified the root cause since then and there's an actual fix for it but I couldn't really be bothered to go further into the rabbit hole if it works by just pointing to the `next` path.

Comment: Why do you need a `server.js` if you are not even running it?